# Can't I blend two mesh objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient-mesh

I'm trying to blend two objects that I created a personalized gradient with mesh tool but I can't apply the blend tool on them.

I've already tried the `Object > Path > Offset Path` but I wasn't able to find this option.

I also tried to rasterize the square and it doesn't work too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Illustrator's Blend feature does not work on Gradient Meshes.

Without *more information* regarding the desired goal, it's difficult to provide any further guidance.